# C string null terminator in oversized buffer

Tags: c, null, c-strings, null-terminated

## Note:

This is a question about pure C. No C++ functions, etc.

---

## Question:

Suppose I `malloc` a buffer that has room for 100 `chars`. Then, I fill only 5 of those slots with actual `chars`. I've heard that best practice is to null all remaining slots in the buffer like this:

```
while (nextAvailableBufferSlot < currentBufferSize) 
{
    buffer[nextAvailableBufferSlot] = '\0';
    nextAvailableBufferSlot++;
}
```

Is this strictly necessary, or can I simply set `buffer[5] = '\0'` and save myself a loop?

---

## Context:

The code in question is called *very* frequently with a buffer size of 4096 and 99% of the strings that get copied into it are much shorter, making the loop above run nearly every time for at least a couple thousand iterations.

It is NOT possible for me to know what size the strings are in advance. And because re-allocs are so expensive, I choose a large buffer size initially. I target desktop-class hardware, so memory is not constrained at all.

Comment: Not really relevant here, but do you truly mean "ANSI C" or do you just mean "strict C", as in, "keep your C++ answers to yourselves?"  If it's the latter, as I assume, the tag is good enough.

Comment: I'v never heard of such best practice, I really wouldn't call it best. Even if you would need to do this, ( for example access the chars out-of-order ), memset would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's strings you are copying you can use `strncpy` to copy the string and the extra buffer space will be filled with `\0` for you.

If for whatever reason you are using `strcpy` or copying the string by hand then yes, you can save yourself the loop because all standard string operations (`strlen`, `strcpy`, etc) will stop at the first `\0` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes you are right. You should really only need one null pointer that goes right after the last char in the array.

The typical answer would be, why not just use char pointers? A string-like char* takes care of the whole headache for you and there are libraries designed around manipulating these more easily. You don't need to allocate memory directly this way. Why do you have a specific reason for needed buffers of exactly 100?

Comment: Thanks - the example here is contrived for simplicity's sake. In my actual project, the buffer *is* a char*. I'm not simply copying a string into it, I'm constructing a string character-by-character as I parse input.

Comment: What do you mean by "why not just use char pointers?" He is using a `char*` already, that's what `malloc` returned.  Are you suggesting he uses a string literal?  And what do you mean by "A string-like char* takes care of the whole headache for you?" String management is one of the most PITA aspects of C, nothing is just "taken care of for you.", unless you're using a string literal which cannot be modified.

Comment: His comment cleared up what he is trying to do. I thought he was straight out mallocing an array of 100 chars instead of making a char*. And no, I am not suggesting using a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

For all practical purposes, you only need to `NUL` terminate the first position after the last position filled.
That's all that's needed for any function to know where to stop when manipulation your string.

Answer (score 0):

Use Calloc() function instead. It will automatically initialize the block of memory to zeros(i.e is equivalent of assigning NULL's, as ASCII code for NULL is 0).Then you will not need to explicitly assign each slot to Null.

Comment: Yea, I'm aware of Calloc. But it's going to do the same thing behind the scenes, which makes it slower. The emphasis is on SPEED because this code gets hammered.